# How to make a Lego continuous conveyor belt

Tags: technic, gears, robotic

So I need to make a continuously working conveyor belt transporting blocks.
I have seen [this post](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/2045/how-to-make-a-conveyor-belt-with-lego-parts), but additionally, as already said, I have to make it work continuously transporting blocks,so I have thought about this:

[image]

There are two problems I foresee:

1. Can conveyor belts be stacked one on top of the other? (they therefore would be slightly uphill)
2. How could I deal with turns?

For problem 2 I have imagined something like in this video:

[LEGO Great Ball Contraption (GBC) Layout 2012.9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUtS52lqL5w)

in which each ball (bricks in my idea) are stored into "tubs".

---

Alternatively if nothing else works I will have to fall back on seemingly easier to do rails. But rails are not conveyor belts. That is totally different.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: If you run your proposed configuration in the opposite direction, each belt drops its inventory onto the next one, which runs at a 90 degree angle. Doesn't that solve your problem?

Comment: The Bucket Wheel Excavator 42055 has a great example of what you want to achieve - a conveyor feeding a conveyor at an angle.  You just need to extend the concept.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the belts to operating in a single plane, you could try having an angled blockage across the corner which diverts the blocks onto the next belt, like this.

[image]

If you don't mind them going slightly up hill then all you need to do is make the one it is dropping off finish up high and have the next one be underneath it. In your diagram the dark green belt runs right into the wall, in my diagram below the dark greening finishes mid-air and the block and drop onto the cyan one.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The first solution might do. I just could find the site that sells those Thomas Convejor. I just googled that name but all others popped out.

Comment: could you please tell me where can I find that Thomas convejor belt?

Comment: @Patrick I don't recall the exact search I did for it but I just grabbed it from Google Images with something like "conveyor belt diverter"

Comment: Thanks in fact this is an industrial conveyor belt